# Progress bar status updated from controller

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

I am developing a web app with Laravel 5.3
To be specific I have a button in my View

```
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="syncAnywayBtn">Yes</a>
```

that fires via javascript

```
$('#syncAnywayBtn').on('click',function(){
  var e = $("#schoolsel");
  var school_id = e.val();
  if(school_id==0)
  {
    alert('Select school!');
  }      
  else{
    var school_name = e.find("option:selected").text();
    document.location.href="/departments/sync/"+school_id;
  }
});
```

some processing in my Controller. I want to display a progress bar on client with updating current progress of the operation. As far as I understand the progress has to be updated only in javascript. But I am stuck at how to communicate my Controller and javascript in my View in order to pass max value and current value for the progress bar.

I would be most gratefull if somebody could give me direction or code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

WebSockets is what you are looking for. This opens a constant connection with the server and allows the server to send messages to the client side.

Laravel has an implementation for this in the form of [Broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting). You need either a nodejs implementation, a redis server or an account on [Pusher](https://pusher.com/) to implement this.